# Spring Inject PersistenceContext

Tags: spring, hibernate, unit-testing, aspectj

Trying to implement a DDD architecture with aspect oriented tests that access a database and check if user exists, using AspectJ LTW...

Currently I am faces with two issues, I don't know if this class is being injected in a Spring context. I have tried to add the

```
//@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
//@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath*:EntityTest-context.xml"})
```

With no sucess. Here is the test that I am trying to run. If you notice I am creating the EntityManager on the @Before I don't know if this is a proper usage, because when I try to find the object that is created I get returned null.

```
package ienterprise.common.aspects;

import ienterprise.common.model.CompanyPosition;
import ienterprise.common.model.InternalUser;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;

//@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
//@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath*:EntityTest-context.xml"})
public class EntityTest {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EntityTest.class);

//    @PersistenceContext(unitName="mysql") // FIXME inject this in unit tests
    private static EntityManager manager;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        EntityManagerFactory mngFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("mysql");
        manager = mngFactory.createEntityManager();
    }

    @Test
    public void createUser(){

        InternalUser someGuy = new InternalUser();

        someGuy.setName("Adam");
        someGuy.setUser("Engineer");

        someGuy.create();

        logger.debug("created user: {}", someGuy);
        //FIXME: Can't find the user in the database.
        InternalUser foundUser = manager.find(InternalUser.class, 1L);

        logger.debug("fetched user: {}",foundUser);


        assertEquals( someGuy, foundUser);
    }
}
```

Our context xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:load-time-weaver/>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" >
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml"></property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

How can I remove the @Before and inject a PersistenceContext?

How can I make sure that my class has a Spring Context?

This is all new stuff for me, and I would appreciate some links to github repositories if there are any with this kind of Spring+Hibernate+AspectJ+JUnit setup.

Let me know if something is not clear or additional detail is necessary.

Comment: Try adding this to your context:

`<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>`